# Збірка макаронізмів як «пан теля пасе»

Tags: фразеологізми, resource-request

Чи десь є словник чи збірка, де зібрано до купи добру частину усталених [українських] макаронізмів?

Менї відома лише одна з часів школи: *пан теля пасе*, що перекручена під французьку. Вона ж і згадана в прикладах до визначїння слова *макаронізм* в [словнику стилістичних термінів](https://slovnyk.me/dict/stylistics_terms/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B8).

> **макаронізми** (від іт. maccheroni — макарони) жаpтiвливо пеpекpученi на лад iншої мови слова: iтал. — *Ми бандито, ганстеpiто…*; фpанц. — *пан теля пасе*; япон. - *то яма, то канава*.

Саме ций термін маю на увазї. Якщо він неправильний, то можите виправити, бо є підстави так вважати, оскільки [словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/makaronizm), як і [вікійпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) — там *макаронічна мова* — наводять геть гинше:

> **макароні́зм**, **у**, *чол., книжн.* Чужомовне слово (або вислів), механічно внесене в мову в незмінному вигляді або спотворене щодо звукової форми та вжите в неприродному контексті, що надає йому гротескного характеру. *Стилістичні функції макаронізмів як засобу мовного гумору досить різноманітні* (Мовознавство, IV—V, 1947, 23).